# failed to build tcmalloc/testing:hello_main in bazel docker container

Tags: bazel, tcmalloc

I used the latest bazel docker container to build tcmalloc cloned from github in the container, I didn't make any modifications on either of them and got this error:

```
ubuntu@e2873c0dacbf:~/tcmalloc$ bazel run tcmalloc/testing:hello_main
INFO: Analyzed target //tcmalloc/testing:hello_main (0 packages loaded, 0 targets configured).
ERROR: /home/ubuntu/tcmalloc/tcmalloc/internal/BUILD:577:11: Compiling tcmalloc/internal/percpu_rseq_asm.S failed: (Exit 1): gcc failed: error executing CppCompile command (from target //tcmalloc/internal:percpu) /usr/bin/gcc -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -fstack-protector -Wall -Wunused-but-set-parameter -Wno-free-nonheap-object -fno-omit-frame-pointer -MD -MF ... (remaining 28 arguments skipped)

Use --sandbox_debug to see verbose messages from the sandbox and retain the sandbox build root for debugging
tcmalloc/internal/percpu_rseq_asm.S: Assembler messages:
tcmalloc/internal/percpu_rseq_asm.S:38: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `,'
Target //tcmalloc/testing:hello_main failed to build
Use --verbose_failures to see the command lines of failed build steps.
INFO: Elapsed time: 2.440s, Critical Path: 2.05s
INFO: 22 processes: 17 internal, 5 processwrapper-sandbox.
ERROR: Build did NOT complete successfully
ERROR: Build failed. Not running target
```

Any help is appreciated.